# Animations are gone after driver installation

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

Trying to find the best driver for my *NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960* I experimented a bit and switched the driver from **xserver-xorg-video-nouveau** to **nvidia-driver-435**.

[image]

After that I recognized that **all window animations were gone**: The app drawer appeard 
immediately without any transition. Same when resizing a window.

So I **switched the driver back** to **xserver-xorg-video-nouveau** but nothing changed. All animations were gone. Even though **animations are turned on**!

[image]

**How do I get the animations back?**

About my system:

- **graphic card:** NVIDIA GeForce GTX 960
- **os:** Linux Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (uses gnome)
- **chosen driver**: xserver-xorg-video-nouveau